# SSIS excel destination , data loads into header row

Tags: ssis

I have `SSIS` package that is supposed to load data into excel destination (template file).

The destination has first row is Title , 2nd row has headers so I do as follows,

`Select * from [TemplateName$A2:$AD10000]`

But what happens is it inserts first set of data (SQL source) into second row of template which contains header names and overwrites but if I select `A3` istead, it gives error since mapping needs column names.

Please suggest, thanks.

Comment: Maybe it should be not `AD` but like this `Select * from [TemplateName$A2:$D10000]`

Answer (score 0):

I just did some testing with this and I get the same exact behavior:

```
MyCol
      <----- Data should start here
1     <----- Data actually starts here
2
3
```

My suggestion would be to remove the column headings in the sheet, uncheck the "First row has column names" in your excel connection and then add the actually headings into your SQL data (Converting everything to text).  Probably would be good to put in a Connect for this as well.